# Macro to alert me when a cell changes value -- popup alert - EXCEL

Tags: excel, popup, alert

I am looking to create a macro to alert me when a cell's value changes. The cells in this particular column can have values of either "OVER" or "UNDER". I would like to write code to alert me via a popup (Message: "Cell A crosses under(over)") when the value changes.

Thanks,

patrick

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to hook in to the [`Worksheet_Change` event](http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/run-macros-change.htm).
Something like this should get you started:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Value = "OVER" Then
        MsgBox "Cell " & Target.Address & " crosses OVER"
    ElseIf Target.Value = "UNDER" Then
        MsgBox "Cell " & Target.Address & " crosses UNDER"
    End If
End Sub

Sub just_testing()
    Dim mycell As Object
    Set mycell = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1)
    Call Worksheet_Change(mycell)
End Sub
```

With this code, changing cell A1's value to OVER (case-sensitive!) will print the message "Cell $A$1 crosses OVER".

---

Edit based on further information provided by OP:
For automatic worksheet changes, you'll need to use the Worksheet_Calculate event (example below).  And for some strange reason, Excel seems to require that you have `=NOW()` anywhere in the worksheet for Worksheet_Calculate to actually fire.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    Dim mycell As Object
    Set mycell = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1)
    If mycell.Value = "OVER" Then
        MsgBox "Cell " & mycell.Address & " crosses OVER"
    ElseIf mycell.Value = "UNDER" Then
        MsgBox "Cell " & mycell.Address & " crosses UNDER"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks. This works great if the cell gets manually changed from OVER to UNDER...but my sheet is linked to an live outside data source. So when the conditional formula (ie, If(a1>b3,"over","under")) recognizes that a1 has become smaller than b3 and the cell changes from "over" to "under" this macro does not seem to work.

Thanks.

Patrick
im: AlphabetPJL

Comment: @patrick:  thanks for the additional info.  I've added another tested example.  Let me know how that works for you.